# Password reset link in email in Laravel Jetstream directs to GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Laravel Jetstream default password reset process sends notification on password reset with the following link:

```
localhost/reset-password?token=xxx
```

However, after clicking the button or following the link in the mail an error is being displayed:

> **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.**

Does anybody know how to debug/resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this route.

```
Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'create'])->name('password.reset');
```

Comment: You are right, used the default Laravel password reset and it works now.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords